# SQLlite values into result array

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have two SQL database tables. How am I able to get result array from data? Since it should be an array of grades which is going to standardDevation function.
As I understand, it should look like this ['Alice' => [5, 4, 5], 'Bob' => [2]] if name is unique and I need each person list of grades.
Prepare sentence is done, but problem is in first `foreach` loop.

```
Student table(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE);
Grade table(id INTEGER, grade INTEGER);

Student table     Grade table
id   name          id    grade
1   Alice           1      5
2   Bob             1      4
3   Carol           1      5
                    2      4
```

```
require_once 'functions.php';

$conn = getConnectionWithData('data.sql');

$stmt = $conn->prepare('select * from student inner join grade on grade.id = student.id' );

$stmt->execute();

$result = [];

foreach ($stmt as $row){
    $name = $row['name'];
    if(isset($result[$row['name']])){
        $result[$name] = [$row['grade']];
    }else{
        $result[$name] = [$row['grade']];
    }
}

foreach ($result as $name => $grades) {
    $std = standardDeviation($grades);
    print "$name: $std\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very similar to your code but a different SQL:

```sql
-- SQLite syntax
select student.name, group_concat(grade.grade, ',') as grades
from student
inner join grade on grade.id = student.id
group by student.name
```

The PHP code:

```php
require_once 'functions.php';
$conn = getConnectionWithData('data.sql');

// Extract grades as a comma-separated list of values per student in SQL
$sql = "select name, group_concat(grade, ',') grades from student inner join grade on grade.id = student.id group by name";
// There is no need to prepare a non-parameterized query
$results = $conn->query($sql);

foreach ($results as $result)
{
 // Make an array out of the comma-separated list of values before calling standardDeviation
 $std = standardDeviation(implode(',', $result['grades']));
 print "{$result['name']}: $std\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the logic directly in a query. SQL is a set-based language, that is efficient at aggregating data.

In SQLite, you can use `group_concat()` for string aggregation. I find that a subquery comes handy here:

```
select s.*,
    (
        select '[' || group_concat(g.grade) || ']'
        from grade g
        where g.id = s.id
    ) as grades
from students s
```

If you want to filter out students that have no grade at all, then a join is a better approach:

```
select s.*, g.grades
from students s
inner join (
    select id, 
        '[' || group_concat(grade) || ']' as grades
    from grade g
    group by id
) g on g.id = s.id
```

Comment: Can I do somehow just with foreach? Since we're only using this once on exam and have used pretty much all the time MySql then i'm afraid it would be too complicated to remember :D